Grammar Pattern: Verb+だけ+Same verb て-form
I have found two examples of this kind of pattern from anime and I wonder how it’s specifically used:
Black Lagoon, main character thinking to self (inoculated) that they’re bad at keeping shut in interrogations:

おっさんと話した時もついつい偉そうなこと言っちゃった
よく考えたら俺言うだけ言って言い逃ればっかだよな
When I talked to
the old guy I acted high and mighty.
Now that I think about it, I tend
to blab all I want... ...then talk myself outta the situation.

Kill la Kill, Ryuko is mad that Kiryuin Satsuki has confided herself in a fortress of sorts when she thought they would fight:

あおるだけあおっといて自分は鉄壁の防御の中かよ
She whips everybody into a frenzy and then sits behind an impenetrable shield?

The second is example is contracted ておく, but this seems to be a pattern utilizing だけ's meaning of "extent".
Is Verb+だけ+Same verb て-form a common grammar pattern to say something like "verb as much as verb"?
What does it really mean? How is it usually used?

This V1だけV1て(V2しない) is an emphatic way of saying "to do nothing but V1" or "to only do V1". It's explained as "JLPTにない文型" in this article: 〜だけ〜て｜日本語能力試験　JLPTにない文型.
While common, its use is almost exclusively limited to blaming someone, as seen in your examples. I don't know the JLPT level for this, but it's common enough and I think it's worth remembering this pattern at your level.
(Note that something like 食べられるだけ食べた and 試験を受けるだけ受けてみよう seem to be categorized as JLPT N2.)
